# How to find the position of the first list item outside a container?

Tags: javascript

I have a div container and inside it a list of items. The list is bigger than container's height and the container has overflow:hidden. How can I find the position of the first list item that isn't displayed by the container?

Comment: Basically: Loop over them, and check if their `offsetTop` is bigger, than the height of the container. (Or `offsetTop` + `offsetHeight`, depending how exactly you need it.)

Comment: Please provide some HTML and CSS that reproduces your issue, and shows what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `getBoundingClientRect()` to compare elements' bounds with the container's bottom position.

The only problem is the horizontal scrollbar, but that could be a very special case which is rare in web UI.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

const borderWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(container).borderBottomWidth);
const containerBottom = container.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - borderWidth;

let hiddenPartial;

container.addEventListener('scroll', checkHidden);
checkHidden();

function checkHidden() {

  hiddenPartial?.classList.remove('partial');

  hiddenPartial = [...container.children].find(elem => {
    const {top, bottom } = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return top < containerBottom && bottom > containerBottom; 
  });
  
  hiddenPartial?.classList.add('partial');

  $partial.textContent = 'The first child hidden partially: ' + hiddenPartial?.textContent;

  const hiddenFull = [...container.children].find(elem => elem.getBoundingClientRect().top > containerBottom);

  $full.textContent = 'The first child hidden fully: ' + hiddenFull?.textContent;

};
```

```css
.container {
  border: 15px solid gray;
  height:70px;
  overflow:auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
p{
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.partial{
  background: yellow;
  border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p>item 1</p>
<p>item 2</p>
<p>item 3</p>
<p>item 4</p>
<p>item 5</p>
<p>item 6</p>
</div>
<div id="$partial"></div>
<div id="$full"></div>
```